# Duplicated items in JupyterLab Advanced Settings Editor

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have the following issue when using JupyterLab on Windows 10 - all items in the Advanced Settings Editor are duplicated.
I have tried reinstalling it after completely cleaning it out i.e. uninstalling all jupyter packages and deleting configuration files in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.jupyter
%APPDATA%\jupyter
%PROGRAMDATA%\jupyter
```

When I edit any of those settings I will see duplicated directories into

```
%USEPROFILE\.jupyter\lab\user-settings
```

For example, I'll see the following two directories when editing the Notebook settings

```
%USERPROFILE\.jupyter\lab\user-settings\@jupyterlab\~otebook-extension
%USERPROFILE\.jupyter\lab\user-settings\@jupyterlab\notebook-extension
```

I am really not sure as to where this is coming from.

[image: Advanced Settings Editor - JupyterLab]

Comment: Are you editing those by hand in an external application by any chance? The `~` prefix usually indicates a temporary file, I wouldn't think that this should be created by Jupyter itself (not saying that you are, just want to bring it up to eliminate a possible user cause).