# Duplicate setting entries in JupyterLab advance settings editor

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using anaconda distribution for python coding and wanted to use code completion in Jupyter Lab and installed Python LSP Server using anaconda prompt and two corresponding identical extensions in Jupyter Lab named "@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp" and "@jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp".

Now I had two identical items of each settings related to above extension such as "Code Completion" appears twice, "Code diagnostics" twice and so on. Please check screenshot.

[image]

Steps tried to resolve issue:

1. If I uninstall any of the above extension through Jupyter Lab or anaconda prompt, the duplicates still remain (but changing values in leftover setting of the uninstalled extension does not trigger update to other duplicate setting), so duplicate issue remains
2. If i uninstall both of the above extensions, both the settings of the extensions (both duplicate menu items) still remain but the icon of the menu items change to something like "reload icon" issue still remains
3. If i reinstall anyone of these extension again, I am back to scenario 1
4. I have tried to find the relevant remaining folder of these extensions in "C:\Users\MyUserName.jupyter\lab\user-settings", the duplicates still remain

PS. I am rebuilding Jupyter notebook assets as it asks after every install or reinstall.

As of now problem still persists, these orphan/ duplicate entries never go away no matter i uninstall any one of them or both. If anyone can help, please. Screenshot is attached.

I know there is another relevant question that existing here:
[Duplicated items in JupyterLab Advanced Settings Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304409/duplicated-items-in-jupyterlab-advanced-settings-editor)
, but scenario for this question is different, As opposed to that question, Jupyter is not creating a temporary setting item. I am not even able to find from where these entries are coming from even if I have deleted extension folders after uninstall.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the end?

Comment: No. I could not.